# My program crashes when using realloc in C

Tags: c, memory, crash, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **Names;
int size = 2;       //Minimum size for 2D array

void main() {

    int i;
    Names = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char *));      // First initaliaion  of 2D array in heap
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        Names[i] = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    printf("\nenter");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%s", Names[i]);

    while (1) {
        size++;
        Names = (char **)realloc(Names, size * sizeof(char *));       //Dynamic allocation of 2D aray
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            Names[i] = (char *)realloc(Names[i], 20 * sizeof(char));

        i = size - 1;
        printf("\nenter");
        scanf("%s", Names[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("\n%s", Names[i]);
    }
}
```

It doesn't crash immediately it depends on the "size" I initialized.
It crashes after 5 allocations for me.
I tried adding free function but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Change `scanf("%s"` to `scanf("%19s"`

Comment: you should check if realloc succeeded

Comment: There's no need to reallocate all the  `Names[i]`, since the new size is the same as the old one.

Comment: calling realloc on an uninitialized pointer is undefined

Comment: As an aside, two points. First, `void main()` is non-portable; unless you are running the program on a platform which cannot accept a return value for a program (e.g., some embedded systems), you should always use `int main()` and end the function with `return 0` or `return <error-code>`. Second, casting the return values of `malloc()`/`realloc()` is not necessary in C, and considered non-idiomatic.

Comment: As @Barmar states, you do not need to reallocate the existing arrays pointed to by the elements of `Names`. You only need to allocate the new array which held by `Names[size-1]`, like so:  `Names[size-1] = calloc(20, sizeof(char));`

Answer (score 3):

After this memory reallocation

```
   size ++;
   Names= (char**)realloc(Names,size*sizeof(char *));
```

the last pointer pf the array of pointers has an indeterminate value because it was not initialized.

As a result the call of `realloc` for the last pointer in this loop

```
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        Names[i] = (char*)realloc(Names[i],20*sizeof(char));
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Before executing the loop you need to initialize the last pointer at least like

```
Names[size-1] = NULL;
```

In fact there is no sense to use the for loop because what you need is to allocate memory for the newly added pointer. The allocated memory pointed to by the early created pointers is not being changed in size.

So instead of

```
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        Names[i] = (char*)realloc(Names[i],20*sizeof(char));
```

you could just write

```
Names[size-1] = malloc( 20 * sizeof( char ) );
```

Pay attention to as you have an infinite loop then the memory reallocation sooner or later can fail.

Also according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```